# Use the same spider to parse details page and pagination page

Tags: scrapy

I have a scraper that use link extractor to move through a pagination and parse the detail page and everything is working fine. Sample code below :

```
class SampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sample'
    start_urls = ['https://www.some-pagination-page.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(@class, "paging-next")]')),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(@class, "b-button_primary")]'), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
      #Code block related to the parsing of item ...
      return item
```

Now I would want to use this same spider to parse directly the detail page without pagination... 
Basically I want to use this spider with scrapyrt and I would like to send a parameter that indicates that is a detail page and the details page as start_url, 
so that I can directly parse that page and quickly return the result.
At the minute I've solved the problem duplicating this crawler and removing just the rules extractors, in this way :

```
class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sample'
    start_urls = ['https://www.some-details-page.com']

    def parse(self, response):
      #Code block related to the parsing of item ...
      return item
```

In order to avoid code duplication, how can I modify the spider so that it could be used with both a pagination start_url and a single details page as start_url ?

Is it possible to just disable the rules ?
What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this would be the best idea, but I am doing this by rewriting the `start_requests` and specifying which callback to use depending on a spider argument:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    ...

    def start_requests(self):
        if getattr(self, 'url'):
            yield Request(
                url=self.url, 
                callback=getattr(self, getattr('callback', 'parse_item'))
            )
        else:
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield Request(url)
```

This way you can specify the `url` argument when calling your spider (and also the `callback` method, default to `parse_item`):

```
scrapy crawl myspider url="http://myurl" callback="parse_item"
```

if not, it will behave as a normal `CrawlSpider` because the `parse` method is the default callback for `Request`s  and the `parse` method is the one in charge of compiling the `rules`.